# The output of ifelse() in R is not proper

Tags: r

I am new to R. The below code shows to print average or above average based on the marks we got.

```
vec=c(78,85,90)
cond=vec>=80
status=ifelse(cond,"Above Average","Average")
print(status)
```

The output I am getting is

```
[1] "Average"       "Above Average" "Above Average"
```

If you see carefully there is a huge gap between the first and second elements.
Can you help me how to solve this in R

Comment: The `ifelse` output is proper. You just don't like how it gets `print`ed. But why do you care?

Comment: try `cat(paste0(status, collapse = "\n"))` - or something similar (don't know what your expected output is)

Comment: @ismirsehregal i think if you change `status=ifelse(cond,"Above_Average","Average")` and `cat(paste0(status, collapse = " "))` it will be closer. but overall i think your answer is correct

Comment: jep -  just thought using a space as seperator is misleading as "Above Average" already contains a space.

Comment: My expected output is "Average" "Above Average" "Above Average"

Comment: One space between each element

Comment: I agree with @nicola: Why is this important? This sounds like an XY problem to me; `print` is a generic function that dispatches a particular method based on the class of the object to print information about the object to the console. The formatting of the output is arbitrary and irrelevant to the internal representation of the object. Can you explain why you are concerned about how `print` displays your `character` vector?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following:

Edit: dropped `paste0` as per @Edo's comment

```
vec=c(78,85,90)
cond=vec>=80
status=ifelse(cond,"Above Average","Average")
cat(dQuote(status, q=FALSE))
```

---

```
"Average" "Above Average" "Above Average"
```

Comment: why not just `cat(dQuote(status))`?

Comment: because I don't like fancy quotes :) - but yes we can drop the `collapse` argument.

Comment: okay, then `cat(dQuote(x, q=FALSE))`. My point is that you don't need `paste0`